# Wrong 'presentingViewController'

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

In my `MainViewController`, I present another view controller through this:

```
MessageViewController *messageController = [[MessageViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[messageController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[messageController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];

[self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];

[messageController release];
```

This will display the view controller correctly. However, when I try to go back to the presenting view controller, which in this case should be the `MainViewController`, this code doesn't work:

```
if ([self.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[MainViewController class]])
    [(MainViewController *)self.presentingViewController setCurrentViewTag:2];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I removed the "if.." condition to force it in setting the current view tag.  An error occurred telling me that the presenting view controller seems to be the `UINavigationController`:

```
[UINavigationController setCurrentViewTag:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8352a50
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening? This code used to work before and I am not sure what changed to make it stop working properly.

**EDIT**

Here is the updated code:

```
ReaderController *readerController = [[ReaderController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[readerController loadWhichViewToShow:2];

[self setDefinesPresentationContext:YES];

[readerController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[readerController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];

[self presentViewController:readerController animated:YES completion:nil];

[readerController release];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Calling `[self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];` doesn't necessarily use the vc you call this on to present the other vc. By default it travels up the vc-hierarchy and presents the other vc on the root view controller. That's why in your case the presenting view controller is a `UINavigationController`.

If you want to force your MainViewController to be the presenting vc, you have call:

```
[self setDefinesPresentationContext:YES];
```

on your MainViewController before presenting the MessageViewController.

Edit: In case someone else reads this: `definesPresentationContext` seems to be bugged or the documentation is wrong. See the comments below and [Cocoa Builder](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/312150-presentingviewcontroller-docs-patently-false.html)

Comment: Your code gives a warning. `Instance method -definesPresentationContext: not found`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this is correct but it doesn't address the real problem. The reason I am doing this: `[(MainViewController *)self.presentingViewController setCurrentViewTag:2];` is because the current view tag is in charge of displaying the view. So if I set it to 1, it should display the login view. If I set it to 2, it should display the home view. However, following your code still produces the same error.

Comment: The presenting vc is still the UINavigationController?

Comment: Yes. Should I just set the MainViewController as the rootViewController in the App Delegate?

Comment: No that wouldn't be good. Could you post your code where you use the `setDefinesPresentationContext:`?

Comment: I'm a little confused, because it should work this way. Unfortunatly I'm not at home and unable to try it myself.

Comment: Hmm, could you add `^{ NSLog(@"%@", readerController.presentingViewController) ; }` as argument for the `completion:` in your `presentViewController` method and tell me what the console sais?

Comment: This is the output: `<UINavigationController: 0x804ab50>`

Comment: That's confusing, Apple stated in a video that setting `definesPresentationContext` to `YES` would force it to be the presenting view controller. Obviously it's not. I'll take a look at it when I'm at home. A workaround would be to declare a custom property for your `MainViewController` on the viewcontrollers you're presenting and set them accordingly before you actually present them.

Comment: On the other hand, if you're using a UINavigationController, your MainViewController has to be the topViewController of it. So another way around would be to instead of calling `if ([self.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[MainViewController class]])
    [(MainViewController *)self.presentingViewController setCurrentViewTag:2];` your could modify that to `if ([self.presentingViewController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[MainViewController class]])
    [(MainViewController *)self.presentingViewController.topViewController setCurrentViewTag:2];`

Comment: @Tobi's answer worked for me, where I am presenting a UINavigationController by setting its root to my modal controller.

Comment: The documentation is correct on NS version but wrong on UI verision

Answer (score 6):

copy of my answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905961/modal-view-controller-not-calling-presenting-view-controllers-dismissmodalviewc/26185639#26185639)

from [Programming iOS 6, by Matt Neuburg](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html):

> On the iPad, when the presented view controller’s modalPresentationStyle is UIModalPresentationCurrentContext, a decision has to be made as to what view controller should be the presented view controller’s presentingViewController. This will determine what view will be replaced by the presented view controller’s view. This decision involves another UIViewController property, definesPresentationContext (a BOOL). Starting with the view controller to which presentViewController:animated:completion: was sent, we walk up the chain of parent view controllers, looking for one whose definesPresentationContext property is YES. If we find one, that’s the one; it will be the presentingViewController, and its view will be replaced by the presented view controller’s view. If we don’t find one, things work as if the presented view controller’s modalPresentationStyle had been UIModalPresentationFullScreen.

TL;DR
1. set `definesPresentationContext` to true on the desired `presentingViewController`
2. set `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` on the desired `presentedViewController`

Comment: Thanks, I think second solution is better

Answer (score 1):

If seems that you need to set three thing in iOS 11.

```
controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```